# How to implement SAML logout to ADFS with openSaml?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, signature, adfs, opensaml

I created Logout Request using openSaml library and added signature

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest ID="_f576971e-5123-49e4-8152-80653dcdfb1a"
    IssueInstant="2015-07-23T15:21:42.254Z"
    Reason="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:logout:user" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://my_host/logout</samlp:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#_f576971e-5123-49e4-8152-80653dcdfb1a">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue/>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue/>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2:NameID
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">_933c8876-9128-431f-b250-08975fde2a24</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2p:SessionIndex xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">8ee4bf85-6792-42f5-b038-a3342a0e0e17</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

And I encoded this and sended to ADFS-server like URL:

https://ADFS_HOST/adfs/ls/SignOut.aspx?SAMLRequest=nVbbk...

But, I got an error from ADFS:

> The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML
>   authentication request.
>
> Additional Data  Exception details:  System.Xml.XmlException:
>   MSIS0018: The SAML protocol message cannot be read because it contains
>   data that is not valid. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No
>   corresponding start element is open.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadEndElement()    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignedInfo.ReadFrom(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, TransformFactory transformFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.Signature.ReadFrom(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ReadSignature()
>   at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.TryReadSignature()
>   at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadCommonElements(XmlReader
>   reader, SamlMessage message)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadCommonElements(XmlReader
>   reader, SamlMessage message)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadLogoutRequest(XmlReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadSamlMessage(XmlReader
>   reader, NamespaceContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String
>   encodedSamlMessage)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage
>   message)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Logout(HttpSamlMessage
>   logoutMessage, String sessionState, String logoutState, Boolean
>   partialLogout, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, HttpSamlMessage&
>   newLogoutMessage, String& newSessionState, String& newLogoutState,
>   Boolean& validLogoutRequest)

And I can't find some information about this problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the ADFS version?

Comment: ADFS version - 6.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

6.3.0.0 is ADFS on S2012R2 :-).  I needed that to take a look in the executable. I didn't want to look in the wrong server. The exception says that there is something wrong with the signature. So true: the digest and signature values are missing.

No offense just a warning. It looks a bit as if you are trying to write this yourself. If so then do realize that it is a **really serious amount of work**. And requires major maintenance effort. And signatures is probably the trickiest part, steer away from that course if you can. Think in months of learning+work....

At first glimpse there seem to be other issues with the request. But discussing them is really a lot of work.... I suggest you do take at least a look at the XML of another implementation. One that comes of the shelve (Kantara certified even better). And make sure you have the same attributes and elements.

Comment: I will describe this problem below

Comment: Could you give advice about another saml implemenatations? I can't find some examples.